# MySQL query is slow?

Tags: mysql

Today I have a problem in my SQL query, my request take most 30 seconds, so I get an error in my php.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT v.ID
     , v.TITLE 
     , v.THUMB  
  FROM video v
  JOIN join_video_date d
    ON d.ID_VIDEO = v.ID 
  JOIN join_video_category c 
    ON c.ID_VIDEO = v.ID
 WHERE c.ID_CATEGORY = $ID
 ORDER 
    BY d.DATE DESC 
 LIMIT $PAGE,24
```

This query take 24 video of category ordered by date, but this query is slow.

I have indexes all tables, example of table "join_video_date"

```
join_video_date (ID, ID_VIDEO, DATE)
```

Index:

```
PRIMARY -> ID
ID_VIDEO -> ID_VIDEO
DATE -> DATE
```

Comment: if this is just happening today, then its probably a server issue. Are you running this locally?

Comment: Does `join_video_date.id` serve any purpose? Also, note that it's common practice to arrange tables such that the WHERE clause references the first table in the query. So that would be `FROM join_video_category c JOIN video v...` - this has no bearing on performance however.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data.  For instance, can one video have multiple categories *and* multiple dates?

Comment: My server is EasyPHP run locally, i can't use primary table because a video is associate with 3 category sometimes

Comment: "My server is EasyPHP run locally, i can't use primary table because a video is associate with 3 category sometimes" - I have no idea what any of that means.

Comment: Did you run this query with `EXPLAIN` prefix? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT v.ID, v.TITLE, v.THUMB  
FROM video v JOIN
     join_video_date d
     ON d.ID_VIDEO = v.ID JOIN
     join_video_category c 
     ON c.ID_VIDEO = v.ID
 WHERE c.ID_CATEGORY = $ID
 ORDER BY d.DATE DESC 
 LIMIT $PAGE,24;
```

The first thing to try is indexes: `join_video_category(ID_CATEGORY, ID_VIDEO)`, `join_video_date(ID_VIDEO, DATE)`.  I assume `video(id)` has an index.

Your query suggests that a video could have multiple categories and multiple dates.  If so, the query is probably not doing what you want anyway.  One way to prevent this is to move the condition on categories to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT v.ID, v.TITLE, v.THUMB  
FROM video v JOIN
     join_video_date d
     ON d.ID_VIDEO = v.ID
 WHERE v.id IN (SELECT c.ID_VIDEO
                FROM join_video_category c
                WHERE c.ID_CATEGORY = $ID
               )
 ORDER BY d.DATE DESC 
 LIMIT $PAGE,24;
```

Comment: So, 1 index for 2 tables ?

Comment: @Johann. . . Two indexes, each with two columns (not counting the primary key on `video`).